# Counting Non-degenerate rectangles Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many non-degenerate rectangles are there of the form $(a \le x \le b)$ and $(c \le y \le d)$ where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are integers between (and including) $0$ and $99$?

Note: A rectangle is degenerate if it has zero area, e.g. $(0 \le x \le 1)$ and $(0 \le y \le 0)$.

- i. Find a formula that's simple but possibly over-counts some
  rectangles or counts degenerates.
- ii. Remove the over-counts from the
  original formula.
- iii. Remove the degenerates from what remains.
- iv. Check your formula for $a, b, c, d$ between $0$ to $3$ by drawing a picture and counting by hand.

Attempt at Solution

There are $100$ possible values for $x$ and $y$, so there are $100\cdot 100 = 10,000$ rectangles total. I'm not sure how to remove degenerates. It would probably be something like subtracting a combination of all degenerate pairs, pairs that contain $x \le 1$ or $y \le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the checkered large square $[0,99]\times[0,99]$, and draw an arbitrary nondegenerate subrectangle $R$ bounded by grid lines. What choices have you made? Note that you were able to choose the horizontal and the vertical bounding lines of $R$ independently.